# Bootstrap Navigation Active Not Working For Links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used a navigation bar from a Bootstrap template, and the template was a one-page layout with the navigation sliding down rather than linking to a different page.

I tried changing the links to link to different pages, but when I do this the active class does not work so you are stuck on a new page without really knowing what page you are on (unless you read the content) because the navigation doesn't tell you.

The active class works when a link is like "#services" for example, so it scrolls down and then the active class works, but when you put something such as "index.php" or "index.html", the active class will no longer work.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

This is the navigation bar HTML:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok....so with this template you're using bootstraps scrollspy function which is what determines active links for the page.  Unfortunately it only takes into account anchors that are on the current page and doesn't utilize the same css for separate pages.  So here's what you need to do.

Any links that go to external pages will need to have the href of the pages name to begin with.  Then you'll have to add in that same a class a `data-target="#page-top"` as well in order to activate the active class on that pages li.

Here's where it gets a little more complicated.  on the external page you're going to have to change the anchor links from the first page to include index.html before each anchor name.  This will ensure that on any other pages you're brought back to those same sections when you click on them.

Also... on external pages you'll want to change the navbar-brand href to index.html so that when you click on you're brand name it will take you back to your homepage instead of the top of your existing page.

So lets say the name of your external page is test.html.  Your index navigation li's will look like this.

```
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a</li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="test.html" data-target="#page-top">Test</a></li>
```

Your test.html navbar brand will look like this

```
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
```

and your test.html navigation li's will look like this

```
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#services">Services</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="test.html" data-target="#page-top">Test</a></li>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to have no effect =S This is the bootstrap navigation I used, you can see the applied CSS that goes with it. I'm having major problems with this and can't seem to find an answer anywhere.  Link: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

Comment: Just modified my answer according to the template you're using.  This will work perfectly now.  Let me know if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The active class should be defined on the `<li>` I think.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy to solve with a little bit of jQuery.

```
// highlight active page in navigation
$(function () {
    $("nav[data-nav-highlight='true']").find("li").children("a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") === window.location.pathname) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

And then add this to your nav element.

```
data-nav-highlight="true"
```

So it looks like this

```
<nav style="height: 1px;" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-collapse collapse" data-nav-highlight="true">
      ...
      ...
 </nav>
```

This will highlight the current page, you can still use your scroll spy to 
highlight active links within the page itself too if you wanted.

*note: I found this code here on stackoverflow but cannot find the post to reference it, if someone can find it feel free to edit my post.*

Comment: This will not work.  He is using a very specific template in which the scrollspy properties and html have been modified.  My first answer yesterday was a simple js fix like yours but this was before he posted a link to the actual template.

Comment: No worries...you were on the right track..he just hadn't posted the link to his template in his question yet.  I edited it in so hopefully it'll show up soon.